# Solving MIP efficiently problems with z3

Tags: z3, linear-programming

I have a reasonably simple MILP (mixed integer linear program):
https://0bin.net/paste/B1IE5l8l#2YLLrptC-l1ml+vesA59tH3167IOCAkJoIUQWbrj/mN

which I can solve with cbc optimally on my low-end computer in about 6.75 seconds.

I have tried to convert it to a format that z3 can take, making a few simplifications along the way and have this:
https://0bin.net/paste/M5dDXNl2#-A3hnStDDZABP69+yBsCdEz818pif15r88SxD8qRwjX

but after half an hour I had to kill it without a solution.

Is there some trick I'm missing, or is z3 bad at solving these sort of MILPs?

Comment: This would not surprise me. There are still lots of things not well understood when comparing different technologies / proof-systems in discrete-optimization. I did not look into your instances nor do i know exactly what Z3 is doing (besides the basic SMT-concept), but some *not too far* intro would be something like: ["Learn to relax: Integrating 0-1 integer linear programming with pseudo-Boolean conflict-driven search"](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10601-020-09318-x).In general i guess Z3 is doing lots of conflict-analysis and would maybe shine more at hard-feasibility problems

Comment: Also does not surprise me. A rewrite to try on your side is "(if depositLine_235 592 0)" -> "(* 592 (ite depositLine_235 1 0))". This will be easy on the solver. The solver may or may not be doing this behind the scenes already. The other obvious thing to try would be a partial weighted max sat solver. There is a yearly competition and you can get candidate solvers from this.